# Legal status of Abraham sending Eliezer to marry Rivka

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, shidduchim-dating, parashat-chaye-sara

I'm confused about the legal status of Abraham sending his slave to get Rivka from Bethuel.

IIRC, Isaac was completely unaware of the mission, he didn't send Eliezer, Abraham was one to send Eliezer and all presents were Abraham's.

What legal status did this mission have - Erusin, Kiddushin, simply bring Rivka to Isaac?

Comment: http://www.torahbase.org/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%95/

Comment: הרי לן ד' שיטות בדבר, דבמסכת כלה מבואר דהיה שליח קידושין, בפרקי דר"א
מבואר דהיה שליח נישואין, לדעת החזקוני היה שליח לקידושין ונישואין, ולבעלי
התוס' במושב זקנים ואף לדעת התוס' בכתובות ז' ע"ב היה שליח למצוא את רבקה
ולהביאה בלבד.

Comment: I think respectfully answers your question that you were right in everything you said it could have been any of them or all.

Comment: @interested It is very informative. Please put it into an answer with the source.

Comment: You are welcome to I gave the source. I only give original answers. and I will delete it from the comments.

Comment: Erusin and kiddushin is the same thing... unless you have proof otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

The [Midrash Lekach Tov 24:53](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Lekach_Tov%2C_Genesis.24.53.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> ...ויוצא העבד כלי כסף וכלי זהב. אלו נתן להם לשם קדושין. כי הראשונים לשם מתנה היו
>
> The servant brought out objects of silver and gold - These were given for the sake of Kiddushin (betrothal). The first (gifts) were for the sake of being (only) gifts...

Comment: You always stop half-way. Please continue: " and therefore the status..."

Comment: And therefore these gift were meant as Kiddushin. What else do you need me to say?! You asked what part of the process of marriage was intended and I brought a case that shows at least kiddushin was performed..

Answer (score 1):

Its a machlokes in the reishonim. Tosafos kesubos 7a says Eliezer was a shliach kiddushin. Moshav Zikeinim (brought in Rinas Yitschak kamma) says Eliezer brought Rivka back to Yitschak and he married her.

Comment: Can you please add @interested's first comment so I can mark it as "accepted"?